Unable to receive the mocked response in my component using MSW, redux toolkit query and react testing library
I am trying to mock the API's using MSW v2 but somehow I am unable to retrieve the mocked response back in my component. Below are the details,
"@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
"msw": "^2.7.0",
"vitest": "^2.1.4"

Redux toolkit query,
export const myApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "partners",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl:
      import.meta.env.MODE === "test"
        ? "https://localhost:3000"
        : 'https://mygatewayurl',
  }),
  tagTypes: ["data"],

  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getData: builder.query<myResponse, Page>({
      query: (paginationOptions) => ({
        url: API_ENDPOINTS.allPartners,
        method: "GET",
        params: {
          page: paginationOptions.page,
          pageSize: paginationOptions.pageSize,
        },
      }),
      providesTags: (_result, _error, { page }) => [
        { type: "data", id: page },
      ],
      transformResponse: handleTransformResponse<myResponse>,
      transformErrorResponse: handleTransformErrorResponse,
    }),
});

export const {
  useGetDataQuery} = myApi;

Taken from redux toolkit documentation
export const handleTransformResponse = <T>(
  response: unknown,
  meta: FetchBaseQueryMeta
): T => {
  console.log("response", response);
  if (response === null || response === undefined) {
    const { status } = meta?.response || {};
    if (status === 200 || status === 204) {
      return {} as T;
    }
  }

  return response as T;
};

Store setup is like this,
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
[partnersApi.reducerPath]: partnersApi.reducer
})

export const setupStore = (preloadedState?: Partial<RootState>) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware()
        .concat(myApi.middleware)
  });
};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = useDispatch.withTypes<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
export default store;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof setupStore>;

Test renderer picked from Redux toolkit documentation
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import type { RenderOptions } from "@testing-library/react";
import type { ReactElement } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createMemoryRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import { createAppRouter } from "@/routes";
import type { AppStore, RootState } from "@/store";
import { setupStore } from "@/store";

interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, "queries"> {
  preloadedState?: Partial<RootState>;
  store?: AppStore;
  initialEntries?: string[];
}

export function renderWithProviders(
  ui: ReactElement,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    initialEntries = ["/"],
    ...renderOptions
  }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {}
) {
  const routes = createAppRouter().routes;
  const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, { initialEntries });
  function Wrapper() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) };
}

MSW setup,
Handler.ts file
const baseUrl = "https://localhost:3000";

export const handlers = [{
http.get(`${baseUrl}${API_ENDPOINTS.allPartners}`, async () => {
    const mockData = [
      {
        data: [
          {
            id: "6",
            partnerId: "1",
            name: "ABC",
          },
        ],
        currentPage: 1,
        pageCount: 1,
        pageSize: 50,
        rowCount: 1,
        firstRowOnPage: 0,
        lastRowOnPage: 0,
      },
    ];
    await delay(1000);
    return HttpResponse.text("hello", {
      status: 200,
    });
}];

Setup test file
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { expect, afterEach, beforeAll, afterAll } from "vitest";
import * as matchers from "@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers";
import { cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import { server } from "./mocks/server";

expect.extend(matchers);

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});

// Start the MSW server before all tests
beforeAll(() => {
  console.log("listening****");
  server.listen({
    onUnhandledRequest: "error",
  });
});

// Reset handlers after each test to ensure no tests are affected by previous ones
afterEach(() => {
  console.log("resetting****");
  server.resetHandlers();
});

// Clean up and close the server after all tests
afterAll(() => server.close());

Object.defineProperty(window, "scrollTo", {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn(),
});

Component where I am not getting the data is being rendered from root using the useNavigate() hook from react router dom v6
export const MyComp = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoading, data } = useGetDataQuery({
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 50,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myComp mounted");
  }, []);

  console.log("partnersList ****", data);
  console.log("isLoading ****", isLoading);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <FullPageLoader />;
  }

  if (!isLoading && !partnersList) {
    toast.error("Something went wrong");
    return null;
  }

return(
<div>***</div>
)

Test file,
import App from "./App";

vi.mock("jwt-decode");

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.clearAllMocks();
});

test("renders the app component - logged in user", async () => {
  const decodedToken = { exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 1000 };

  vi.mocked(jwtDecode).mockImplementation(() => decodedToken);

  const { debug } = renderWithProviders(<App />, {
    initialEntries: [`/?token=some-token`], // my home route
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    console.log(debug());
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});

Vite config
test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: "jsdom",
      setupFiles: "./src/setupTests.ts",
      mockReset: true,
      clearMocks: true,
      coverage: {
        provider: "istanbul",
        include: ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"],
        exclude: [
          ...coverageConfigDefaults.exclude,
          "**/config/**",
          "**/main.tsx",
          "src/ui/icons",
        ],
        reporter: ["text", "html", "json"],
      },
    },

Now i can the logs from the response that it's being sent and also logs from useEffect that component is mounted, But I am unable to receive the mocked response in the component.
the logs prints undefined and the isLoading stays true.
Please assist if I am missing anything in the setup or the configuration.

Can you [edit] to share where/how you create the MSW server and load the handlers for the API endpoints you want to handle? Does that const baseUrl = "https://localhost:3000"; match what the API slice ends up using during your unit testing? The API slice looks to be dependent on an environment variable.

@DrewReese Yes it's dependent on env variable, that's why I added the check for test env and provided absolute url since msw in node doesn't support relative url's so I provided a test base url to mock. And my API is intercepted and I can see the response being printed under the handleTransformResponse() method, but it doesn't reached my component where I need the response. There i just get undefined and my isLoading from RTK is true as always.

@DrewReese I already added the handler.ts file and also provided by setuptest.ts file. What other file is required?

Yes, those are the handlers, but I was asking about where the handlers are passed to the mock server you are using, e.g. the import { server } from "./mocks/server";, the server used in the unit test code.

@DrewReese it's being injected via setuptest.ts file. beforeAll(() => {   console.log("listening****");   server.listen({     onUnhandledRequest: "error",   }); });
Please have a look at setuptest.ts file I provided.

But where and how are the handlers passed to the server when the server is created? If they are never passed to the server when it's created, or they are incorrectly provided, then the server can't, and won't, ever know what API requests it needs to provide mock responses to. Certainly somewhere you've some const server = setupServer(....) call that receives the handlers and creates the server, right?

@DrewReese sure, I have the mocks/server.ts file which have this code `import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { handlers } from "./handlers";
export const server = setupServer(...handlers);
`
And then I am importing the server in my setuptest.ts file

Oof, sorry for chasing down the rabbit hole of ensuring that your MSW server was setup with the handlers. I just took a closer look at your handler and it returns a text response with "hello" as a value, but RTK Query looks to be configured to receive JSON response values (the default). Is the problem simply that your MSW handler isn't returning that mockData value, or any JSON value?

@DrewReese I saw, Apologies for the mistake, I was testing it with text response as well, but as you saw, it should return the mockData from the handler. httpResponse.json(mockData).
Problem is I am not receiving this mock json data in component. Once the API is intercepted, i can see the response logged in my handleTransformResponse method, but I just receive undefined in the component.

Ok, so for the code you have shared in the post there is way too much going on to effectively debug it without a [mcve] or sandbox demo we can run. Too many moving parts for testing a single unit of code. What are you actually trying to unit test there? The MyComp component? The App component? Is the unit test just not waiting for the component to get the API response and rerender? Try to simplify/reduce the complexity to narrow down where the issue appears.
